# LAPACK installation along with lapack-devel and lapack-dev

Tags: c++

I wanted to have a complete installation of the La-pack on my Ubuntu 14.04.

So, I made the following installation commands on my system: `sudo apt-get install libblas-dev checkinstall` `sudo apt-get install libblas-doc checkinstall` `sudo apt-get install liblapacke-dev checkinstall` `sudo apt-get install liblapack-doc checkinstall`

But I need to make sure that the `lapack-devel` and `lapack-dev` are also installed. How do I confirm it ? If I havent installed then how to install it because when I tried `sudo apt-get install lapack-devel` it gave :

```
E: Unable to locate package lapack-devel as a response And same for lapack-dev
```

Comment: @ubuntu99: This is what is written in readme of armadillo library:"For example, when installing the "lapack" package, also install  the "lapack-devel" or "lapack-dev" package.  "

Answer (score 7, accepted):

lapack 3.5.0-2ubuntu1 source package has been built into many binaries thus installing these binaries will install lapack, execute following in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev liblapack-doc-man liblapack-doc liblapack-pic liblapack3 liblapack-test liblapack3gf liblapacke liblapacke-dev
```

[Click here for more details and downloading source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lapack/3.5.0-2ubuntu1)

Comment: You do not need to download every single package built from the sources. You only need `sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev` (static version) or `sudo apt-get install liblapacke-dev` (dynamic version).

Comment: Your choice of LAPACK vs. LAPACKE should also be informed by whether you plan to use the C or FORTRAN interfaces [see question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875415/difference-between-lapacke-and-lapack)